# Standardizing the Community Wiki "Resource List"

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, list-questions

A community wiki "Resource List" has been found useful on many sites.  Here is a list of those I have found:

- [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/resources-for-learning-chemistry)
- [Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian)
- [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)
- [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)
- [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)
- [Online Legal References](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/online-legal-references)

It would be useful to standardize this, sort of like a FAQ analog.  For example, one thing that has been asked several times is whether the Resource List should be on the main site or the meta site.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing was the purview of the Documentation project, now mothballed. The newer system called Articles also retreads this ground, in a very different way. (Articles are more integrated into Q&A than Documentation ever was, and are curated by a subject-matter expert.)

In any case, it’s using the Q&A platform in a way other than how it was originally intended, and the hack is not ideal. It would be nice if there was some official support for the feature.

Comment: Ah, Documentation. They never did iron the kinks out of it. They now have Articles, which hopefully won't end up the same way. (You may want to edit.)

Comment: I attempted an edit, and ended up with a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

I would second this.
In my experience, posts for resources get closed or removed quickly as they don't fit in the pattern and are rated "opinionated".
While both might be true, I think there's a real need for these resource lists - maybe even resource lists on resource lists.

##### "But they don't fit in to the style of Stack Exchange. Why not use a different service for that?"

(My experience:) Quality of Stackexchange. Any other online community on broad topics do not deliver the quality of SE/SO. Be it people posting uneducated comments that never get removed or simply the presentation of sites (like forums, where one has to navigate 8 pages of nonsense until the answer finally appears before it get's flooded by another 8 pages of *Thank you*s).

##### Maybe a first step: Provide unified tag

Maybe as a first step that wouldn't require site changes creating a unified tag throughout the communities expressing this kind of post would be nice. Perhaps `resource-list` or `reference-list`.
A more "programming-intensive" job would be to *announce* this kind of feature, so people know it's there.
This might help people find the right resources for the topics they worry about - as most of the time *finding the resource* is a very critical and time consuming aspect.

Comment: Well, there is software recommendations, an entire SE site just for lists of recommended software. These kind of lists just don't fit within SO.

Comment: I understand it doesn't fit within SO. But isn't the community wiki already a step in this direction? I.e. the style of SO kind of allows community-worked up stuff?